# Gatsby Build Fails Randomly on AWS Amplify: Field "[x]" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, gatsby, aws-amplify

I currently am creating a website using Gatsby v4 and I keep running into an issue with building on AWS Amplify. *Building locally works fine every time*, however, when I build on AWS Amplify, a random amount of GraphQL query errors appear with the general format of:

```
Field "[x]" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.
```

This error *usually* appears when a file path (usually for an image) is misspelled or written in the wrong format, causing graphQL to recognize it as a String as opposed to a path to a file.

Sometimes there's only one of these errors, other times there's two or three, and occasionally, if I'm lucky (about 35% of the time), there will be no errors and it builds properly. My packages.json is the following:

```
 "scripts": {
    "develop": "cross-env GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md,css}\"",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^4.0.53",
    "@pittica/gatsby-plugin-recaptcha": "^2.0.3",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.35",
    "gatsby": "^4.24.4",
    "gatsby-cli": "^4.24.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-anchor-links": "^1.2.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-html-attributes": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.16.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.13.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "1.7.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.16.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.24.0",
    "gatsby-source-build-date": "^1.0.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-csv": "^4.23.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^4.16.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.22.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.16.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2"
  }
```

Is there any way for me to configure AWS or Gatsby so that it builds correctly 100% of the time (assuming there are no other errors)?

I have tried updating packages, configuring different versions of node and npm, and changing build commands and settings to no avail.